# The ionic side menu is under the ios template

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have a problem, I am developing an app to event and the build to android it works correctly, but to ios not, the side menu is under the menu from ios, I don't know wha't is the problem

http://tinypic.com/r/2luc4k4/9

Comment: the card with image and title scientific programme is your side menu?

Comment: I started my project using ionic start app sidemenu

Comment: have you used menu-toggle?

Comment: yes, it come with the side menu